# Copying from double pointer to int array. Is this correct?

Tags: c

I have a double pointer data->mono_channel, where I would like to cast all the doubles to integers and put them in an array.

```
int frames = data->audio_info_save->frames;
short buffer[frames];
double* p;
int i = 0;
for (p = &(data->mono_channel)[0]; p < &(data->mono_channel)[frames]; p++) {
  buffer[i] = (int) *p;
  i++;
}
```

The purpose is that ALSA takes an integer array of samples, and my samples are in doubles.

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_writei(playback_handle, buffer, frames)) != frames) {
  fprintf(stderr, "write to audio interface failed (%s)\n", snd_strerror(err));
  exit(1);
}
```

So somehow I need my doubles to be casted to integers.

I don't hear any sound. So is the casting done correctly?

Comment: What are the ranges of your double values? Note that if they're between, say, 0.000000 and 0.9999999 the cast to `int` will convert **all of them** to `0`.

Comment: Does this work if you just use a function to return an int value of p? I.e. buffer[i] = double_to_int(*p) ? I think gcc is optimizing your intention away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks okay, it'd be easier to just:

```
for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
  buffer[i] = (int)pdata->mono_channel[i];
}
```

Is the data PCM encoded? That might be your problem.

Comment: What does it mean to be PCM encoded? The data comes from libsndfile. Does that make it PCM encoded?

Answer (score 1):

The samples probably need to be scaled from [-1,1] to [min, max], where min and max are minimum and maximum integer values for integer samples.

Answer (score 1):

If `data->mono_channel` is an array of `double`s, the casting is correct (although your code is overly complicated -- you should just use index `i` as the control variable in the loop, and use it to index the input array of `double`s as well as the resulting array of `int`s).

The resulting silence may be due to the input `double`s not being in the right range (i.e., you might need some scaling!).  What do you see if you print out some of those `double`s?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to scale and clip the input values, clipping can be quite slow, but there's a trick. So if your input is in range[-1,1], then you may use the following code:

```
double fclip( double value, double start, double end ) {
  return 0.5 * ( fabs(value-start) + (start+end) - fabs(value-end) );
}
...
for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) {
  buffer[i] = (short)fclip( 32767.0 * pdata->mono_channel[i], -32767, +32768 );
}
```

Comment: BTW, I once found that on http://musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=5#81 - this website is a good source for dsp related code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is of type `short[]`. Have you configured ALSA PCM to expect 16bit values? Have a look at this [example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#ZScnKi-LryE/alsa-lib-1.0.14rc2/test/pcm_min.c&q=pcm_min.c) from ALSA project.

Comment: That's a really cool example. Now I at least get some noise =) Thanks a lot for this. I will build on top of this instead.